# C# - Object reference not being modified

Tags: c#, oop, exception, properties, reference

I have the following code:

```
public static void Main() {
    Exception exception = new Exception("1", new Exception("2"));
    Exception inner = exception.InnerException;
    inner = new Exception("3");
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This should print an exception with message `"1"` and with an inner exception, that has the message `"3"`

However, when printed, the inner exception has the message `"2"`.

How can this happen? Am I not modifying the reference object? Is a copy of the object returned to me when I call `exception.InnerException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This should print an exception with message "1" and with an inner exception, that has the message "3"

No, it shouldn't - because you're not modifying the object that the `exception` variable refers to at all. Instead, you're declaring a variable and giving it an initial value using `exception`:

```
Exception inner = exception.InnerException;
```

This copies the value of `exception.InnerException` (which is a reference) to the `inner` variable. Then in the next line you're ignoring the current value and just giving `inner` a different value:

```
inner = new Exception("3");
```

That doesn't change anything about `exception`. The fact that the original value of `inner` happened to be fetched from the `exception.InnerException` property doesn't affect the assignment of the new value to `inner` *at all*. You might as well just have written:

```
Exception inner = new Exception("3");
```

You can't change `Exception.InnerException` after the exception has been constructed - the `InnerException` property is read-only. Even if it *were* a writable property, your code wouldn't have done what you wanted. Instead, you'd have needed:

```
// This won't work because InnerException is read-only, but it would *otherwise*
// have worked.
excetion.InnerException = new Exception("3");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I not modifying the reference object?

No, you are not.

> Is a copy of the object returned to me when I call exception.InnerException?

No, a copy of the *reference* is returned to you.

Here's what is happening:

```
Exception inner = exception.InnerException;
```

`inner` now *references* the object that `exception.InnerException` also references.

```
inner = new Exception("3");
```

`inner` now references a *different* object.  The object that id *did* reference is unchanged.

Comment: Thank you both, now I understand it perfectly